# Function to generate random word combinations

Tags: asp-classic

I have a MySQL database table holding 6,318 random words.

I have a bit of code which does a select from that table, and puts the words into an array.

I have written a function to extract random word combinations a set number of letters long - e.g. 8 characters long.

The problem I have is that the function doesn't seem to be that random. As there are 6,318 words in the table, I know that there are many hundreds of word combinations which are 8 characters long, but I find that the output of the code often repeats the same combinations.

This is the code:

```vb
<%

SQL1 = "SELECT fld_un FROM j_un2 ORDER BY rand()"

'##############################################################################

set p1RS = oConn.Execute(SQL1)
list1 = p1RS.GetRows
p1RS.Close

block1 = ""
For row = 0 to UBound(list1,2)
 block1 = block1 & list1(0,row) & ","
next
Erase list1

wordArray1 = split(block1, ",")

Function f1(str)
    found = "no"
    max=6138
    min = 1
    do while found <> "yes"
        Randomize
        rand1 = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
        rand2 = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
        word = wordArray1(rand1) & wordArray1(rand2)
        if len(word) = str + 1 then 
            found = "yes"
            f1 = word
        end if
    Loop
End Function

for i = 1 to 10
    bob = f1(8)
    response.write bob & "<br />"
next
%>
```

Sample output:

```
shootnail
epeestove
buggersix
splatsane
urbanbash
pinevital
shootnail
epeestove
buggersix
splatsane
```

As you can see, some combinations repeat themselves - e.g. from the extract above, only these 2 combinations are unique:

```
urbanbash
pinevital
```

If I do this (e.g. output 20):

```vb
for i = 1 to 20
    bob = f1(8)
    response.write bob & "<br />"
next
```

Then none of the combinations are unique:

```
raftsniff
hitactive
nineridge
tartmagma
turnbuyer
klutzpity
adoptlose
bookspell
herbshare
raftsniff
hitactive
nineridge
tartmagma
turnbuyer
klutzpity
adoptlose
bookspell
herbshare
raftsniff
hitactive
```

Am I missing something obvious - I can't work out why the combinations repeat like they're doing.

Comment: Should you not be declaring the variables so they belong to the scope of the function `f1()`? I'm not saying that is the issue, just don't like seeing untidy functions.

Comment: The issue is the default seed used by `randomize()` see - [VBScript generating same random number when in loop - how to solve?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5286358/692942) You should only seed `randomize()` once per page, so remove it completely from the function and the `For` loop and just call it at the top of the page once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBScript generating same random number when in loop - how to solve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286337/vbscript-generating-same-random-number-when-in-loop-how-to-solve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is misconceptions you may have picked up from other examples on the internet when it comes to using `Randomize()`.

### What does Randomize do?

`Randomize()` works by generating a seeded value that by default is taken from the system time *(as this is constantly changing the result should always be random)*. This seed is then used by `Rnd()` to generate the random value.

### So what's the problem?

When `Randomize()` is placed inside a loop that can be computed multiple times a second, it in effect re-seeds with the same value.

### And the solution?

As `Randomize()` provides an initial seed for `Rnd()` to then use there is no reason to call it multiple times in the executing code. Calling the `Randomize()` function once at the top of an Classic ASP page is enough to seed the value for `Rnd()` to then use through-out any code *(loops or otherwise)*.

To fix the specific issue in the question, take `Randomize()` completely out of any loops in the code and place it *(preferably near the top of the page)* to set the random seed once.

With the example in the question it should look something like this;

```vb
<%
'Call Randomize() once to set the seed for the page.
Randomize
SQL1 = "SELECT fld_un FROM j_un2 ORDER BY rand()"

'##############################################################################

set p1RS = oConn.Execute(SQL1)
list1 = p1RS.GetRows
p1RS.Close

block1 = ""
For row = 0 to UBound(list1,2)
 block1 = block1 & list1(0,row) & ","
next
Erase list1

wordArray1 = split(block1, ",")

'Removed Randomize() from the f1() function, Rnd() will now use the
'seeded value set at the beginning of the code.
Function f1(str)
    found = "no"
    max=6138
    min = 1
    do while found <> "yes"
        rand1 = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
        rand2 = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
        word = wordArray1(rand1) & wordArray1(rand2)
        if len(word) = str + 1 then 
            found = "yes"
            f1 = word
        end if
    Loop
End Function

for i = 1 to 10
    bob = f1(8)
    response.write bob & "<br />"
next
%>
```

---

### Useful Links

- [SO - VBScript generating same random number when in loop - how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286358/692942)