# how to generate random date DDMMYYYY format between start date-end date range every time in vb scripts?

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vb scripts please help me.

I'm generating Random year by appending last two digits randomly as shown bellow but i want to generate random date DDMMYYYY format between start date and end date provided by user.

```
Randomize
tmp = Int((92 - 70 + 1) * Rnd + 70)
tmp1= "01/05/19" & tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this as a starting point

```
Option Explicit

Function getRandomDate( startDate, endDate )
    getRandomDate = DateAdd( _ 
        "d" _ 
        , Fix( DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate ) * Rnd ) _ 
        , startDate _ 
    )
End Function

Dim startDate, endDate 
    startDate = CDate("2016/03/10")
    endDate = CDate("2017/09/30")

    Randomize

Dim i
    For i = 0 To 100
        WScript.Echo getRandomDate( startDate, endDate )
    Next
```

It just calculates the number of days between the start and end dates and selects a random in this range of days to add to the start date.

Comment: Without [`Randomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38d7ckek(v=vs.84).aspx) the seed will not be truly random - From [Rnd Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e566zd96(v=vs.84).aspx) - *"Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer."*

Comment: @Lankymart, I know, thank you. Now included. As the original code included it, I decided to post the bare minimum to demostrate the usage, but probably I should have included it.

Comment: I would keep the `Randomize` inside the `getRandomDate()` call that way it's self-contained and less likely to get missed when calling `getRandomDate()` in future.

Comment: @Lankymart, It generates side effects. What happens when you want to obtain the same list of dates (ex. when testing)?. What happens if the rest of the code needs the PRNG not reinitialized? And, also, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5286337/2861476)

Comment: You'd store the returned values back to a collection / array of some sort so you can test them to your hearts content. The side effect is the values returned are "random", how do you expect to test and get the same result when the whole point is to have a random value? Personally, if you have a function called `getRandomDate()` you expect the value returned to be truly random, you can only guarantee that by calling `Randomize` as part of it's execution.

Comment: @Lankymart, I understand your point of view, but one of the possibilities of `Randomize` is to re-start the same sequence of random numbers. If some code uses this option and your proposed function, it will fail (it will not work as intended) as the `getRandomDate` function reinitializes the PRNG in each call. This is a side effect of including the `Randomize` inside the function. As I see it, It is the programmer who should decide when/where the PRNG reset should happen.

Comment: Ok I see the point, in which case I'd probably have something like `getRandomDate(startDate, endDate, reSeed)` where `reSeed` is `Boolean` flag to apply `Randomize()` or not, that way you can still test but also re-seed without requiring to remember to call `Randomize` before calling `getRandomDate()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer and the correct usage of Randomize. A pseudo random number generator creates a sequence of 'un-predictable' numbers; restarting the algorithm for each number uses the machanism against its specs.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I never said it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to [@mc-nd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42154281/1)

When using `Rnd()` to generate random numbers you sure to use [`Randomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38d7ckek(v=vs.84).aspx) to initialise the Random Number Generator using the System Time as a seed value or this happens.

```
Option Explicit

Function getRandomDate( startDate, endDate )
    getRandomDate = DateAdd( _ 
        "d" _ 
        , Fix( DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate ) * Rnd ) _ 
        , startDate _ 
    )
End Function

Dim startDate, endDate 
    startDate = CDate("2016/03/10")
    endDate = CDate("2017/09/30")

Dim i
    For i = 0 To 10
        WScript.Echo getRandomDate( startDate, endDate )
    Next
```

1st Output:

```
15/04/2017
07/01/2017
02/02/2017
21/08/2016
28/08/2016
24/05/2017
17/03/2016
16/05/2017
16/06/2017
17/04/2017
04/04/2016
```

2nd Output:

```
15/04/2017
07/01/2017
02/02/2017
21/08/2016
28/08/2016
24/05/2017
17/03/2016
16/05/2017
16/06/2017
17/04/2017
04/04/2016
```

Add the `Randomize` statement to the code to see the difference;

```
Option Explicit

Function getRandomDate( startDate, endDate )
    getRandomDate = DateAdd( _ 
        "d" _ 
        , Fix( DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate ) * Rnd ) _ 
        , startDate _ 
    )
End Function

Dim startDate, endDate 
    startDate = CDate("2016/03/10")
    endDate = CDate("2017/09/30")

Dim i
    'Call the random number generator with the system time as the seed.
    Call Randomize()

    For i = 0 To 10
        WScript.Echo getRandomDate( startDate, endDate )
    Next
```

1st Output:

```
14/11/2016
28/09/2016
26/05/2016
06/01/2017
22/09/2016
13/06/2016
12/11/2016
05/03/2017
05/05/2016
01/05/2016
03/02/2017
```

2nd Output:

```
08/03/2017
20/01/2017
18/04/2016
29/11/2016
16/08/2016
07/05/2016
06/10/2016
27/01/2017
22/07/2016
19/07/2016
21/09/2017
```

It's an easy thing to miss but makes a BIG difference.

Comment: Code (and comments) show a dangerous misconception of (pseudo) random number generation. The generator should never be re-seeded for   each next number in the random **sequence**. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gstemp/2004/02/23/random-thoughts-and-passwords-revised/.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner wasn't sure, to be honest over the years I've used it never had an issue with it being *less* random, but if Eric say's it's less I guess I have to concede. Thanks for the link. I must admit though that makes packaging "Random" functions a bit of nightmare if you have to make sure `Randomize` is called at some point before your function is run.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner wow, down-vote really?...nice touch. even adjusted my answer to take on board your comments.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date
Date1 = 10/02/2017
Date2 = 10/06/2017
iDiff = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2, vbMonday)
Dim RndDate As Date
Randomize
RndDate = DateAdd("d", Int((iDiff * Rnd) + 1), Date1)
```

I find simple way to generate random Date.

Comment: Isn't that what @mc-nd has [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42154281/692942)?

Comment: You also realise that `As` is not supported in VBScript you call that in VBScript it will fail with `Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement`.